# SqlServer Management Studio 2016 High DPI issue

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have installed **SqlServer Management Studio 2016** and **Visual Studio 2015** on the same host with Windows 10.
While text in Visual Studio 2015 (and in Windows at all) is crisp the text in SSMS looks like rendered with blur option.

**How to make the text in SSMS sharp?**

The current state is in sample below (to see the difference you have to view it in 1:1 scale)..

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I have just installed **SSMS v17.0** and the issue is still present. The way to solve it is to modify properties of a shortcut of the application. On my laptop the file is located under `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft SQL Server Tools 17`. On **Compatibility** tab need to **Override high DPI scaling behavior** and set it to **Application**:

[image: Properties image]

Comment: Works for me, but why is this necessary?  SSMS 2014 doesn't have that problem.

Comment: @kristianp, I have no idea, sorry.

Comment: probably as MS decided that proper DBAs-and-the-like (who were possibly going to effect their bottom line - think enterprise licences for mega-corps) would find this bug and the easy fix... super quick and get on with their lives - so it was not worth investing massively and risking seriously screwing their complex UI codebase for SSMS; just to fit perfectly with the huge range of possibilities the Win8.1? world brought with it's scaling factors etc. they could just rely on people who really-needed-to-know => finding out ¬ Here on the dubya-budya-webbs! Fairplay! seems efficient to me.